# How to our-ride Djangorestframework serializers.save() method for creating multiple model object on single request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create multiple model object on single request, each one has its own unique id

models.py

```
class DemoUserRequested(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="profile",verbose_name=("user"))
    name_of_obj =  models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    count_of_obj =  models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    Uuid =  models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True,null=True)# i am generating the unique id
```

serializers.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # user = UserSerializer('user', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DemoUserRequested
        fields = ('id','name_of_obj','count_of_obj','Uuid')
        read_only_fields=('id','Uuid') # i'll generating the unique id 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_of_obj
```

views.py

```
def perform_create(self,serializer):
    serializer = serializer.UserProfileSerializer(data=self.request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # Cheking how meny objects user want create 
        count = serializer.validated_data.get('count_of_obj', 1)
        #if user choose to create 4 objcts I want run this loop crate 4 model objects
        #this example count = 4 
        for x in range(count):
            unic_id = uuid.uuid4()
            #I want create 4 objects 
            serializer.save(Uuid=unic_id)
```

But every time i run this code it's our riding single model instance and updating 4 time's, and end-up creating one object . How can i solve this? 
 is this possible to do in djangorestframework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.   It's very easy to do.  I've got it working by doing this

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer = serializer.UserProfileSerializer(data=self.request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # Checking how many objects user want create 
        count = serializer.validated_data.get('count_of_obj', 1)
        #if user choose to create 4 objects I want run this loop crate 4 model objects
        #this example count = 4 
        for x in range(count):
            unic_id = uuid.uuid4()
            #I want create 4 objects 
            userobt = DemoUserRequested(
                name_of_obj=serializer.validated_data['name_of_obj'],
                Uuid = unic_id
            )
            userobt.save()
```

That simple :)